# How use match.call in a nested function

Tags: r, function, arguments

I tried to get the list of names and the expression in `...` in a function composition. Let's suppose a function:

```
g <- function(...) {
  print(as.list(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE))$...)
}
```

And if we call:

```
g(rnorm(5), par = "a", 4 + 4)
```

We get:

```
[[1]]
rnorm(5)

$par
[1] "a" 

[[3]]
4 + 4
```

And it's nice: we can get the expression call for every argument and validate. But I need this but in a *function composition*:

```
f <- function(...)  g(...)

f(rnorm(5), par = "a", 4 + 4)
```

But I get:

```
[[1]]
..1

$par
[1] "a"

[[3]]
..3
```

I'm reading some chapters http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html but I can't find the solution yet. I know, I need kepp studying.

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the parameters, you don't need the entire call. Just use `substitute()` to access the `...` rather than `match.call`

```
g <- function(...) {
    print(substitute(...()))
}

f <- function(...)  g(...)
f(rnorm(5), par = "a", 4 + 4)

# [[1]]
# rnorm(5)
# 
# $par
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[3]]
# 4 + 4
```

There's also [Hadley's recommendation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute) of

```
g <- function(...) {
    print( eval(substitute(alist(...))))
}
```